# How to customise the shown outputs from a py-script <py-repl> REPL

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, pyscript

I can create a REPL and see the output using

```js
<py-repl
    id={`my-repl`}
    auto-generate='false'
    std-out={`output`}
    std-err={`err-div`}>
</py-repl>
<div id={`output`} class="replOutput"></div>
```

As I understand, when I press "start", `py-script` executes some code under the hood to run the code in the REPL and create new `<div>` elements for each new line of output.

Currently, it is creating new output divs, every time you run the REPL. I want only the most recent outputs to be shown. I tried using CSS to select just the final element (using `:nth-last-child()`) but if I have multiple print statements, only the last print output is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/f3157b377f843be4777124e591d1469723b5ec9f/pyscriptjs/src/components/base.ts#L44). It seems that you can set `py-repl` attribute `output-mode` to `replace` (default seems to be [`append`](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/9de154595a72818fe29265ba876bc05d406ad3d2/pyscriptjs/tests/unit/base.test.ts#L56)):

```
<py-repl
    id={`my-repl`}
    auto-generate='false'
    output-mode='replace'
    std-out={`output`}
    std-err={`err-div`}>
</py-repl>
```

Comment: Does that file show all the attributes available? I’ve been looking for that source code but I don’t know TypeScript

Comment: I don't see any other option. I'm not a contributor to the project though!

Comment: So I finally had the chance to try this - it doesn't show multiple print statements (probably because it's now not appending the second print statement evaluation). Can you think of any other fix? I want the following code to show like it would in a normal repl:

```python
print(1)
print(2)

>>> 1
>>> 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to achieve that with pyscript `py-repl`. You can still take a look at [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/) directly. They have an example of [console](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/console.html)